# Redundant Javascript this in object method?

Tags: javascript, this

Noob question, searched but don't find an answer to this particular question.
I'm constructing an object, and referencing the parameters of the argument using the 'this' keyword:

```
function Obj(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.addMe = function() {
    alert(this.a + this.b + this.c);
  };
}
```

My question is a simple one: if a, b, and c exist solely within the object (in other words, there are no global variables declared using the same names), is the 'this' keyword required when using them within the addMe() method? Could the method not simply be written as:

```
this.addMe = function() {
  alert(a + b + c);
};
```

When I run this code by creating a new instance of Obj, it works exactly the same either way. And (not that I would do this) if I create global variables for a, b, and c different in value from the arguments I use when instantiating the new Obj, these have no bearing on the results from the method call. So, am I missing something that will come back to bite me if I don't use 'this' in the method?

Comment: That depends on what `a`, `b` and `c` are, and if there's a chance that they'll be reassigned at some point. If the `this` versions are never reassigned, they should effectively be the same.

Comment: If you want to get the initial state of the instance from the method, then you'd return the math by arguments. I you want to get the current state of an instance from the method, then you would return the math by properties of an object.

Comment: Like `@Carcigenicate` said, but since you have those as public properties, you'll want to use `this`, as reassignment is an option.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you know that `this.a` (for example) will never be reassigned, then yes, they should effectively be the same.

That's a *big* if though. What if you forget later that you intended to never reassign them? Then you have a weird bug that may be difficult to track down.

Example:

```js
function Obj(a) {
  this.a = a;

  this.show = function() {
    console.log(this.a);
    console.log(a)
  };
}

var obj = new Obj(1);
obj.show();

obj.a = 2;
obj.show(); // OOPS!
```

Note that the second call to `show` will give two different values. The `show` function creates a *closure* around the original value of `a`; essentially saving it. It remains unchanged when `this.a` is reassigned.

Unless you have good reason not to, just use `this`. Explicitly stating your intentions is usually the way to go when in doubt. Saving yourself a few keystrokes is rarely worth the potential headache down the road.

Comment: Just to add to this, the reason this happens is because of closures. When the function `this.show` is defined, Javascript effectively replaces `a` with the state of `a` at the time the function was created (that is, `1`) When you change it to 2, the `a` referenced from within the function is still 1.

Comment: Good call. I'll see if I can fit that in somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the difference/problem of using `a + b + c`

```js
function Obj(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.addMe = function() {
    console.log('addMe', this.a + this.b + this.c);
  };
  this.brokenAddMe = function() {
    console.log('brokenAddMe', a + b + c);
  };
}
var o = new Obj(1,2,3);
o.addMe(); // should be and is 6
o.brokenAddMe(); // should be and is 6
o.a = 4;
o.addMe(); // should be and is 9
o.brokenAddMe(); // should be 9 but still is 6
```

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks for the answer. As I said, noob.

Answer (score 0):

With the way you've defined your `addMe` function, yes; you could simply close over `a`, `b` and `c` and use them. However the problem is that this is generally a wasteful way to define your methods, because *every* instantiation of an `Obj` will involve construction of a new `addMe` function.

In general, people tend to attach reusable methods to the prototype outside of the constructor function, either by relying on the ES6 class syntax or doing `Obj.prototype.addMe = ...`. In both cases the `a`, `b` and `c` constructor parameters are not in scope, so you must rely on the properties available in `this`.